# client - server application crashes

Tags: c#, multithreading, client-server

I have a client server application. The clients log in an account on my server. The thing is that my server sometimes crashes and although I have all kind of wrapped in a try-catch statement, I get no message.

The server I have implemented is here: [simple threaded tcp server](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-simple-threaded-tcp-server).

Did anyone encounter a crash like this?  Is there a place that I can find an error log for the app?

I'm kind of desperate, so ANY ideas would be great. Thanks.

Comment: and by the way, i am accessing variables from multiple threads without using a lock statement. Could that be the problem for the crash ?

Comment: What error are you getting when your server crashes? There should be a stack trace in there, pointing you to some portion of the code. Once you find that, show us the code that is causing the issue, if you haven't found the issue yourself.

Comment: no , there isn't !! That's so weird ! The program just crashes ! I am searching for every possibility . either the server code doesn't work or the other code i've written has a problem

Comment: If the service raises an exception, hopefully it will be logged in your server's event log. For Windows XP: Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Event Viewer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application is possible to crash because of unhandled exceptions even if you have all functions wrapped in try-catch block because of multi-threading operations.

```
try
{
   var t = new Thread(()=>
      {
          Thread.Sleep(5000);
          throw new Exception();
      });
   t.Start();
   //t.Join();
}
catch
{
    //you can't deal with exception here
    //even though you uncomment `t.Join`
    //the application will crash even there is a try-catch wrapped
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you kept this part of the example code? 
Add a Console.WriteLine right after the catch...

```
 catch
    {
      //a socket error has occured
      break;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're running under Debug mode in Visual Studio, you might consider enabling CLR Exceptions to propagate to user control. I believe they're disabled by default, which sometimes causes hung applications without any debugger feedback. [This article on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/debugger/visual-studio-debugger-fails-to-catch-unhandled-exception-for-a-windows-form-or-wpf-application) might be of interest.